# Adding Users to the AAD Group via MS Graph

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add users to the AD Group via MS Graph API using application permission, and can't give GroupMamber.ReadwriteAll permission as this will allow app registration to add people to any group which is a security concern. My app registration is the owner of the AAD group.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***Please note that, to add users to the Azure AD Group via MS Graph API, you must have one of the below permissions as mentioned in this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).***

[image]

Without having at least one of the above permissions, you cannot add users to the Azure AD group.

***I assigned the app as owner of the group like below:***

[image]

***I tried to add users to the Azure AD group without granting any of the above permissions and got the error like below:***

[image]

***After granting the required permission, I was able to add the user to Azure AD group successfully like below:***

[image]